# ReactJS - Dynamically return components using names in a JSON

Tags: reactjs

I have implemented few components and I need to return it in another component by using the names in JSON.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ToggleButton from '@mui/material/ToggleButton';
import ToggleButtonGroup from '@mui/material/ToggleButtonGroup';
import AWSLogs from '../supportProviderTables/AWSLogs.js';
import AnalyticsEvent from '../supportProviderTables/AnalyticsEvent.js';
import Assignment from '../supportProviderLists/Assignment.js';
import AllComponents from '../supportProviderTables';

export default function ColorToggleButton() {
  const [alignment, setAlignment] = React.useState(null);

  const handleChange = (event, newAlignment) => {
    setAlignment(newAlignment);
  };

  const buttonSet = [
    {
        value:"profiles",
        text: "Profiles",
        components: [
            {text: "Assignment"},
            {text: "AnalyticsEvent"},
            {text: "AWSLogs"}
        ]
    }
  ];
  
  return (
      <div>
        <ToggleButtonGroup
            color="primary"
            value={alignment}
            onChange={handleChange}
        >
            {buttonSet.map((item,i) => {
                return <ToggleButton value={item.value}>{item.text}</ToggleButton>
            })}
            
        </ToggleButtonGroup>
        {alignment !== null ? alignment.map((item,i) => {
            return (buttonSet.map((ele,j) => {
                if(item === ele.value){
                    return (ele.components.map(data => {
                        console.log(data.text);
                        const ComponentName = AllComponents[data.text];
                        return <ComponentName />
                    }))
                }
            }))
        }) : <div></div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The output is expected to return all the components relevant like below
[image]
But it doesnot return the components and shows an error as "AWSLogs is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter" Can anyone help me to do this?

C

Comment: Share the content of ../supportProviderTables/AWSLogs.js. It should export AWSLogs as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply export a string and expect React to know that it's a component. The bare minimum is that you have to create a key-value pair, where you manually map each string to the component you want to return.

```
const components = {
'A':<A/>,
'B': <B/>,
'C': <C/>,
}
```

So, then when you get the `ComponentName` in your component, you can return it like

`return components[ComponentName]`, which will return the respective React component.